# pyqt5: QStatusbar shows data when mouse moves in the QTableView's item

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtableview

I want to show the item's data inside a QTableView on QStatusBar when the mouse moves in the item and stop showing data when mouse move out the item.
I found a signal `entered` which only support for mouse enter the item but dosen't support mouse out .
Is there any avalable signal for this purpose or I have to inherit from QTableView and write some customized code?

[image]

Comment: If you're using QStandardItemModel, use [`item.setStatusTip()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditem.html#setStatusTip). If you're using a custom model, implement the return value for the `Qt.StatusTipRole` (or subclass the model and override `data()`).

Comment: I tried to use ```item.setStatusTIp()``` for test purpose with this code: ```self.model.item(1,1).setStatusTip('test')```, but when I hover on the item nothing shows on the status bar.
Did I miss something?